# Magento REST API access using store id

Tags: magento2.2, multistore, products, rest-api

I am using **Magento 2.2 REST API**. I could not find the URL to get Products using **store id**. Using **Store Code** in URL is not working. The URL I tried is:

> **http://{{serverIP}}/index.php/rest/store_code/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=20&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1**

Comment: did you get the product list in the standard URL without the store_code?

Comment: Yes. It worked without store_code.